# JS turning dot seperated strings into hierarchical objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a list of strings to an hierarchical tree.

An example of a JSON I would get would be:

```
{
    "log_names": [
        "one",
        "one.one",
        "one.two",
        "one.three",
        "one.three.one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "three.one",
        "three.one.three.two",
        "four.one.some.more.stuff"
    ]
}
```

**output**
Here, each level is an object, and each sublogger is a child of it's parent.
Each logger is an object, that might contain other objects that are his subloggers. And moreover, like `three.two` in `three.one.three.two`, because there isn't another logger under `three.one.three`, it would be considered as a single logger and not a father logger. Another example is `four.one.some.more.stuff`. Because there are no other loggers under `four`, it would just be a single logger under the same logic as before

```
{
    "one": {
        "one": { },
        "two": { },
        "three": {
            "one" : { }
        }
    },
    "two": { },
    "three": {
        "one": {
            "three.two" : { }
        }
    },
    "four.one.some.more.stuff" : { }
}
```

I'm having difficulty of implementing the above logic (no other sons so it's just one logger and not a father logger).

Some advises or even code examples would be nice

Comment: Yeah, some code examples would be nice. How about you add what you tried?

Comment: your data is not valied, `"one.three"` here three is a value, but in the next line, three should be an object, with `one`as value. and what is with `two`? ther is no property.

Comment: how should be converted this string `"three.one.three.one"` ?

Comment: Your desired result is not a valid object. You have a property called `two`, which has no value. Are these all meant to be arrays?

Comment: It took me some time and I finally realized that Im a douche. Im fix that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the algorithm looks for an existing key in the object and takes it for the next iteration, if not, generate a new object, with the rest of the array as key.

```js
var data = { "log_names": ["one", "one.one", "one.two", "one.three", "one.three.one", "two", "three", "three.one", "three.one.three.two", "four.one.some.more.stuff"] },
    object = {};

data.log_names.forEach(function (a) {
    var temp = object;

    a.split('.').every(function (b, i, bb) {
        if (b in temp) {
            temp = temp[b];
            return true;
        }
        temp[bb.slice(i).join('.')] = {};
    });
});

console.log(object);
```

Comment: the thing is, that `one` and `one.one` + `one.two` is a different thing. The context here is loggers. `one` is a logger. `one.one` and `one.two` are sub-loggers, that are children of `one` but are separate. `one` does not rely on `one.one` and `one.two`, and they don't rely on him.

Comment: but you given data structure is not valid. how should i cope with it?

Comment: My apologies, I've corrected the output. Although, if you mean the input, it's definitely valid.

Comment: Hey man, it's awesome. I'm just gonna do some work on replacing the commas in the key names to dots and it will be finished. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ups, sorry about the commas, now there are dots.